# Firefox,Chrome Anchor Issue - padding removed from container element CSS

Tags: css

I have a div which contains my page content ( #content )

div #content has padding top of 20 px.

in the #content div I have an anchor link href="#my_form" that is linked to a form lower down on the same page.

When i click the anchor the page scrolls down to the form OK but for some reason the padding is removed from the top of #content div?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks again

**CSS**

```
<style>
#content {padding-top:20px} 
</style>

HTML


<div id="content" class="clearfix">


<div class="title-container"><h1>Apply for credit now</h1></div>

 ...
 ...

<a href="#application_form"><span>Apply now</span></a>

...
...
...
...
...

<a name="application_form"></a>


<form>...</form>

</div>
```

when Apply now is clicked the div 'title-container' moves hard up against the top of the #content div - padding is removed? Doesn't happen in IE though

Comment: Yes, post the code or point to an example page.

Comment: I pasted your code into a html and looked at it in Firefox, but the problem you're describing isn't showing up. The issues is likely in some other code on the page, so to help, we'll need to see the entire page.

Comment: Yes i guess its some other element. Well, i cant post the entire page and markup so i guess ill have to  slowly track it down one element at a time. Thank for your help anyway.

Comment: One thing to check, I've been seeing several clearfix classes lately with height set to 0, which has been causing trouble. I doubt that's related in this case, but I'm beginning to hate clearfix classes.

Comment: no its not clearfix. I have several other wrappers for the framework so im guessing must be one of them. Im thinking its a position relative issue somewhere.

Comment: Do you have a demo page that you can link to? It doesn't have to be the entire page, just enough that the problem is reproduced. Out of curiosity, what doctype are you using?

Comment: I found the problem. overflow:hidden on the outer container. Thanks you guys for your help.

Comment: @John you should post the answer below, in the answers section, and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved

overflow:hidden on the outer container.